# unable to use Ready Boost functionality with my Western Digital 500 GB External Hard Drive

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, readyboost

I have Intel Pentium 4 CPU 3.06 GHz, Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate with 80 GB Hard disk & 1.50 GB of RAM. I also have a Western Digital 500 GB of external hard disk. Recently, I heard about Ready Boost. When I tried to Ready Boost my external hard disk, it said this hard disk cannot be used for Ready Boost.
I didn't like that. I don't know why it happened... :(
I recently lost both my 4 GB USB drives.
I anyhow use my external HD for Ready Boost.
Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

ReadyBoost is meant for use with flash-based media.  If you have a 500gb drive, is it flash?  If it is a normal drive (i.e. platters and spindles) it will not work with ReadyBoost.  Only solid-state drives (no moving parts).

Answer (score 0):

ReadyBoost isn't designed for use with regular hard drives.  The set of requirements is pretty detailed, but in practice it means only flash-based media is fast enough to be used for ReadyBoost.  I'd recommend you look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReadyBoost#Overview) for the exact specifics, but basically you shouldn't expect to use ReadyBoost with anything but a thumb drive.

Answer (score 0):

Ready Boost is essentially a cache for the hard disk. A basic concept of any cache is that the caching media must be faster than the media being cached. Otherwise the cache would not be of any benefit and is likely to actually impair performance.

When Windows starts it checks external drives for any that qualify for use in Ready Boost. To qualify it must meet some specific requirements. They are such that it seems unlikely that few if any conventional drives could meet them.

Flash drives tend to have a transfer rate slower than most hard drives but they do have a very fast seek time. Ready Boost takes advantage of this. For large sequential reads it will go directly to to the hard drive to take advantage of it's good transfer rate. For small random reads it will go to the flash drive to take advantage of it's fast seek time.

The problem with a conventional drive in Ready Boost is that it has a modest transfer rate, probably no better than the hard drive and possibly slower. And as a conventional drive it also has a poor seek time. Either way the Ready Boost drive is of no value.

You might conceivably fool Windows into using a conventional drive for Ready Boost but you would gain nothing. It would likely cost performance.

If you want to use Ready Boost get a flash drive. But don't expect much. Ready Boost is most beneficial with low RAM systems with a slow hard drive. With 1.5 GB RAM and a reasonably fast 80 GB drive gains, if any, are likely to be very modest.